# FIPS mode, signature verification failed

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, linux-kernel

I am building a kernel with FIPS mode on. I followed most of the procedures described on Red Hat documentation [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-Federal_Standards_And_Regulations-Federal_Information_Processing_Standard.html).

I also created a `hmac` signed `.vmlinuz` file. 
After installing `dracut-fips` and running `dracut -f`, I see that `initramfs` contains `fips` related objects.

Then, I added the following to the `kernel` in the boot command line,

```
fips=1 boot=/dev/sda1
```

But, kernel panics with the following message,

```
end Kernel panic - not syncing: Module crc32c_intel \
                   signature verification failed in FIPS mode
```

I see that in the kernel config, I have

```
CONFIG_CRYPTO_CRC32C=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_CRC32C_INTEL=m
```

This configuration is also on a CentOS box, which I am able to boot in a FIPS mode following the above procedure, but not for my recompiled kernel.

How can I go on to debug this ? Thanks for any help.

#### EDIT

Here are some more info (see attached image) after turning KERNEL DEBUG option ON.
[image]